# XNA PC Networking

Tags: networking, xna

A few days ago, I started watching the Nathan Biefeld XNA Networking videos on Youtube in hope of making a game I could play with my friends over the internet. While developing the game, I used two computers both on the same network to test with, and I was able to make a connection using my internal ip (something like 127.0.0.1). Now, I am giving my friend my public ip address to connect with, and it is not working. By the way, I am not using Windows Live to handle my game's online capabilities.

This is the error message he receives:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Does anyone know the cause of this problem? All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your router and/or firewall is blocking the incoming connection. You need to configure port forwarding on the server side, and/or allow your application through your firewall(s). How you port forward depends on your router, but I've used [PortForward.com](http://portforward.com/) to guide me through it for certain games sometimes, but in general terms, you can:

- Connect to your router's admin panel. Often accessed at `http://192.168.0.1/` or `http://192.168.1.1/` in your browser. If those don't work, you'll have to RTFM.
- Find the section for port forwarding, or port triggering, and add a record to indicate that incoming connections on a specific port are okay.

Modern versions of Windows come with [Windows Firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall). There's more information than you'd ever want on [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). In short, open it up from the start menu and allow inbound connections to your application.

I might try adding the Windows Firewall exception first because it's easier.